# TFS Reporting service Manual Configuration failed

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

i have installed sql server with reporting service on data tier server  [Reporting service is up and running] and TFS on application server.

now I am trying to configure Reporting service on TFs2010 with admin console

**Warehouse tab**  Green mark

**Analysis tab**   Green mark

**Reports tab** have an error 
the server that you specified was not found or can not be reached. Specify another server.

Note:

- The URLs in the report tab for WebService and report manager is correct because i can access them via browser using tfsreport credentials.
- i have turn off the firewall and still no luck.
- i have tried to install reporting service on application tier and connect it to data tier still no luck

Can you help guys .

Regards

Comment: Any errors / error codes being displayed?  Anything in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

Try to see how to Configure Report service in [TFS installation and configuration video guide](http://tfs10enterprise.codeplex.com/)

Try also to see this post

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/how-to-recreate-the-data-warehosue-and-the-analysis-service-for-tfs/